# Does the update() in the new FlutterFire fail if the document reference does not exist?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am migrating my Flutter app to the new Flutter Fire version.  Previously, when I wanted to update a document I would just use `document(documentID).setData({}, merge: true)` because I know setData will target the document reference if it exists and just create one if it doesn't, and the `merge: true` would allow me to now replace the whole document if I just wanted to add a field or two or something like that.

Now with the new FlutterFire you have to do `document(id).set({})` and there isn't an option to do `merge: true` without using `SetOptions(merge: true)` which I feel is not best practice (just as my previous method wasn't).  I would like to start using `document(id).update({})` but I don't want to run into errors.

**So to reiterate my question from the top:** does `document(id).update({})` fail if there is no document with the specified id?

Comment: "which I feel is not best practice" You might want to either explain why you feel that way, or reconsider the feeling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will fail.  The document must already exist if the update is to succeed.

If this is not what you want, then you should go back to using set with merge, or use a transaction to see if the document exists before updating it.